# fast approximated hypotenuse without squared root

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, computational-geometry

imagine you are driving a car on a road going to a town, then you see a sign "yourDestTown: 84 km"

i am trying to find a way to calculate fast distances just as informational reference info, where precision is not important as speed (actually i am using this formula for a points of interest minecraft plugin)

- how to get a *fast* and acceptable approximation to distance?
- is this way ok?
- have anyone a better or faster solution?

###### FAST APPROXIMATED HYPOTENUSE WITHOUT SQUARED ROOT FOR DISTANCE CALCULATIONS

i inspired this formula in quake3 "fast inverse square root"

let's consider a right triangle with "A" as long cathetus and "B" as short one,

```
     B
 +-------
 |      /
 |     /
A|    /
 |   /H
 |  /
 | /
 |/
```

we can take a proportional triangle with long catetus 1 and short one
variable by dividing B/A

```
 b = B/A
 +-----
 |    /
1|   /
 |  /h
 | /
 |/
```

we can find a value to operate with b to find the hypotenuse "h", that later    could multiply with "A" to find original hypotenuse lenght "H"

the function of hypotenuse against short leg is

```
      ______
     /     2
h = V 1 + b


  |        ,´
  |    _,-´
 1|---´  
  |
h |
  |
  +----------
  0         1  
            b
```

i noticed this curve looks similar to an hyperbola, which involves division
i believe this should be the better approximation
but my current math knowledge does not allow me to follow this calculatations

i think it also looks like the zone of a parabol near the foci

i want to find a value "V" in function of "b"
so that multiplying "b*V" finds a good approximation of "h"

i found that the approximated equation "h ~= 1 + 0.43b^2 "
satisfies fairly well the problem between range 0 <= b <= 1

```
                      ______
             2       /     2
    1 + 0.43b   ~=  V 1 + b
```

i think the curves looks very similar in specified range, so summarizing
with A (longer) and B being right triangle legs and H being hypothenuse we got

b = B/A
2
H ~= A (1 + 0.43b )

until does not fit perfectly is ok for me since i just use it for information
(a minecraft plugin that prints the approximated distance between 2 portals)
maybe a correction could be added later by someone else (graph made it with geogebra online calculator)

[image: graph]

i found the max differences are about 0.015 (1.5%) in x~=0.6 and x=1, not so high for just informational info... maybe if you are driving a car and a road sign says "destTown: 203km" instead "200km" the difference is negligible, at 100km/h you will reach the town in 2:00 instead 2:02

would be useful if someone finds a more precise method with just basic operations (+-*) (no roots, trigonometry, logarithms or expensive ones) or huge lookup tables, at most a 2nd degree equation with a constant as it was for fast inverse square root

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: What's the question here, in a nutshell?

Comment: It is customary to ask a question on a question & answer site.

Comment: my question is "how to get a fast and acceptable approximation to distance" ..  and if this way is ok .. and if maybe someone have a better solution

Comment: "i think if someone finds a more precise method ...
could be a revolution in math and computing"  That's  bit of an overstatement, don't you think!

Comment: if "someone" ...  not me

Answer (score 1):

Some observations and explanations, because I'm not 100% sure that there's actually a question here:

- Note that $y = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$ *is*, in fact, a branch of a hyperbola, since it can be rearranged as $y^2 - x^2 = 1$.
- You say that you can approximate $y = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$ by $1 + 0.43 x^2$. Notice that the first few terms of the Taylor series of $y = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$ centered at $x = 0$ are
  $$y = 1 + 0x + \frac 1 2 x^2 + ...$$
  and since $0.43 \approx 0.5$, this explains the approximation you found. In fact, since the next term of the series is $-x^4 / 8 \le 0$, using a coefficient a little under $1/2$ for the $x^2$ term might be helping the approximation.

So you have some nice observations, but unfortunately it's probably not going to lead to a revolution....

Comment: a revolution .. who knows .. maybe is not so probable but not imposible .. if it is will not leaded by me for sure ....    could you post a more accurate constant or technique?  ... as the method is not exact, i tried to enclose similar looking areas between curves and found 0.43 worked well

Answer (score 1):

How do you measure precision? Average over errors? Or some integral conditions? For small $b$ you have 
$$\sqrt{1+b^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}b^2-\frac{1}{8}b^4 + O(b^6).$$
Obviously your approximation is inaccurate for small $b$ if you look at the relative error.

The quadratic minimax approximation 
$$\sqrt{1+b^2} \approx 0.995961+0.066459b+0.355837 b^2 $$

has a maximum absolute error of about $0.004$ over the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: an approximation is inherited inaccurate ...  i just used geoebra webapp .. and find that the most inaccurate values are +-0.01% approximately

Comment: Yes, but your since coefficient is 0.43 instead of 0.5 your approximation is suboptimal for small $b$. That's why I asked how you measure the precision of the approximation.

Comment: open www.geogebra.org/graphing and enter these 3 functions  ....  sqrt(1+x^2)  (original) ... y=1 (limit)  ... 1+0.43*x^2  (function in question)  ..   zoom in a lot and see there are similar  (how to insert line breaks here??)

Comment: i dont know what do you men with "suboptimal"  ...  but for a=b (45 deg) i know the optimal value is sqrt(2) .. but it leaves the curve too much open for lower values, so i found 0.43 caught similar looking areas between maximun and minimus values  ....  you could play with geoebra and try different constants

Comment: I don't get your point. Again: please give us your question and measure of precision. Your approximation has a maximum absolute error of about $0.016$, where for the function $0.995961+0.066459b+0.355837 b^2$ it is about $0.004$ i.e. about a quarter of yours.

Comment: i edited the starting post to include the questions

Comment: i can't edit this comment not add line breaks ...  but with your maths knowledge that excels mine, would be interesting if you found a better constant or a faster and/or better approximation formula

Comment: I have already given a better approximation with the same polynomial degree and much smaller absolute error. **A last time: If you do not provide your approximation requirement this discussion is fruitless.**

Comment: i am not expert in math as yours, i even does't know what a polynomial degree is... additionally i see your proposal doesnt meet the original requirement due square roots, that are computationally intensive and i want to skip... have a look to "fast inverse square root" in wikipedia to see what i mean... i want some similar but for distance (hypotenuse), with an alternative procedure that involves just basic operations and magic numbers... the precision i wont give you because i even doesn't know how to measure it, i just estimated graphically by trial and error (see image link at 1st post)

Comment: gammatester : it seems you are like obsessed with precision ... sorry i have no precision, just speed and efficiency......  so don't use this function for nothing serious, just for informational purposes or constrained envorinments (road signs, waze distances, some games, embedded systems, etc)

Comment: this approximation is slighty more precise, but a little more complicated too (yet no square roots or divisions) `y = 1.016+0.43 x^2 - 0.086 (x-0.43)^2` ... ![](https://i.ibb.co/KFfwqQc/dist-v2.png)